# Modify a script in order to get current year and previous year instead of just the 12 Rolling months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use the following script to 12 Rolling months. How can I modify it in order to get the current year and the previopus year?

```
declare @start date = convert(date,dateadd(M,-12,getdate()))
declare @end date = getdate()
;with months (date)
AS
(
    select @start
    union all
    select dateadd(month,1,date)
    from months
    where dateadd(month,1,date) < =@end
)
,
-----------------------------------------------------
--List of periods (12 months from today)
-----------------------------------------------------
list_param as (

select 
left(convert(varchar, Date,112),6) as [Period]
from months)
-----------------------------------------------------
--Calculation parameters
-----------------------------------------------------
select 
Period,
Period AS Inv_M,

left(convert(varchar, dateadd(M,-1,convert(date,Period+'01')),112),6)  AS Inv_M_1,
case when Period=left(convert(varchar, getdate(),112),6) then convert(date, getdate()) 
     else dateadd(M,1,convert(date,Period+'01')) 
end as Backlog_M,

case when Period=left(convert(varchar, getdate(),112),6) then convert(date,dateadd(day,-day(getdate()-1),getdate())) else convert(date,Period+'01') end as Backlog_M_1,
left(Period,4) as Inv_YTD,
left(Period,4)+'01' as Start_Inv_YTD
from list_param 
order by Period;
```

As result I get the following result:

```
> Period    Inv_M   Inv_M_1 Backlog_M   Backlog_M_1 Inv_YTD Start_Inv_YTD
> 201802    201802  201801  2018-03-01  2018-02-01  2018    201801
> 201803    201803  201802  2018-04-01  2018-03-01  2018    201801
> 201804    201804  201803  2018-05-01  2018-04-01  2018    201801
> 201805    201805  201804  2018-06-01  2018-05-01  2018    201801
> 201806    201806  201805  2018-07-01  2018-06-01  2018    201801
> 201807    201807  201806  2018-08-01  2018-07-01  2018    201801
> 201808    201808  201807  2018-09-01  2018-08-01  2018    201801
> 201809    201809  201808  2018-10-01  2018-09-01  2018    201801
> 201810    201810  201809  2018-11-01  2018-10-01  2018    201801
> 201811    201811  201810  2018-12-01  2018-11-01  2018    201801
> 201812    201812  201811  2019-01-01  2018-12-01  2018    201801
> 201901    201901  201812  2019-02-01  2019-01-01  2019    201901
> 201902    201902  201901  2019-02-11  2019-02-01  2019    201901
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change how you populate @StartDate. Switch it to something like this to get the start date of the previous year.

```
dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
```